# creation of dashboard in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

For the creation of a dashboard I need to find out the way to get the count of the items in a field of a list. How to get the same in real time?

Let’s say I have a list with the following fields;

Quarter >>>>  Batch#  >>>>>>  In field/Packed/Shipped

For eg, if the entries for the first list is as given below;

Quarter >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Batch# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  Status

Q1 ------------------------------------B1------------------------------------ In the field

Q1 ------------------------------------B2 ------------------------------------In the field

Q1------------------------------------B1 ------------------------------------Packed

Q1------------------------------------B2 -----------------------------------   Shipped

Q1------------------------------------B2------------------------------------   Shipped

NOW, I need to get a dashboard list where in it give the below result;

It should look like;

Status >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  Batch 1 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Batch 2

In the field ------------------------1----------------------------------1

Packed     ------------------------- 1-----------------------------------0

Shipped------------------------- 0----------------------------------2

Please help upon how to create a dashboard like the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of operation is generically called Cross Tabulation or often 'Pivot' operations.

You may be able to do this using SharePoint Designer, the Data View Web Part (dvwp) and some very fancy XSLT - but its not going to be easy. This is a great start on the DVWP.

- [EUSP - Data View Web Part - the
  basics](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/05/08/new-article-series-laura-rogers-on-data-view-web-part-basics/)
- And then the series by [Jim Bob
  Howard - Extending the Data View web
  part](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/?s=extending+the+dvwp)

Otherwise I think you're looking at developing a custom web part.

Alternatively there is a commercial web part that will allow you to do [cross tabulation and pivot operations on data from SharePoint lists](http://www.pentalogic.net/pivotpoint) *(disclaimer - my own company sells this, but its very relevant to the question asked)*.

Comment: thanks ryan i was struggling for the creation of the dataview webparts in sharepoint designer and was finding it hard to get a decent web help. the links that you have given looks cool. let me go through the same. thanks once again.