# DASHBOARD creation in MOSS 2007 using DVWP and XSL

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, xslt

### my earlier post pasting over here between the lines;

For the creation of a dashboard I need to find out the way to get the count of the items in a field of a list. How to get the same in real time?

Let’s say I have a list with the following fields;

Quarter >>>> Batch# >>>>>> In field/Packed/Shipped

For eg, if the entries for the first list is as given below;

Quarter >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Batch# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Status

Q1 ------------------------------------B1------------------------------------ In the field

Q1 ------------------------------------B2 ------------------------------------In the field

Q1------------------------------------B1 ------------------------------------Packed

Q1------------------------------------B2 ----------------------------------- Shipped

Q1------------------------------------B2------------------------------------ Shipped

NOW, I need to get a dashboard list where in it give the below result;

It should look like;

Status >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Batch 1 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Batch 2

In the field ------------------------1----------------------------------1

Packed ------------------------- 1-----------------------------------0

Shipped------------------------- 0----------------------------------2

Please help upon how to create a dashboard like the above.

### -------------------------------------------------------------------

i asked help for above question;
[creation of dashboard in sharepoint 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152822/creation-of-dashboard-in-sharepoint-2007)

as per the Ryan suggested i tried creating a DWVP webpart with XSL coding to create the dashboard. Now i have emcoundered a problem.

First I created a list where in i have,

Status >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Batch 1 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Batch 2 , as the list fields

In the field ---------------X1--------------------------Y1

Packed -------------------- X2--------------------------Y2

Shipped-------------------- X3--------------------------Y3

here i was trying to inser ta formula for X1, X2 and X3 which are unique as per each item in the row "Status"

But as soon i give a formula for X1, same get applied to the entire colum ie X2 and X3 :(
Is there any way to create specific formula for X2 and X3 too .. Y1, Y2, Y3 repectively.

KIndly help

regards,
Jiben.

Comment: Why didn't you use the same user account - don't be lazy, log on and add back to the SO community! ;)

Comment: :D think i have forgotten the way to login using the old credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can provide a different formula for each row that is processed. All you can do in this situation is build a formula that can provide the result you want based on the values of the row.